# "Safe" Windows Module API Wrapper

Tags: c#, windows

Recently I've been toying around with C# interop and the Vulkan API. Today I discovered the [`SafeHandle` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle) and decided I'd try to wrap the Windows API calls that I depend upon; please see the code below and let me know if I've made any errors during the implementation process.

**Code:**

```
public static class Library
{
    [Flags]
    public enum LoadLibraryType : uint
    {
        NONE = 0x00000000,
    }
    [Flags]
    public enum ModuleHandleType : uint
    {
        NONE = 0x00000000,
    }

    public sealed class LoadLibrarySafeHandle : SafeHandleZeroIsInvalid
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr libraryHandle);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        private static extern bool GetModuleHandleExW(ModuleHandleType moduleHandleType, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string libraryName, out IntPtr libraryHandle);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr libraryHandle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string procedureName);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryExW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string libraryName, IntPtr fileHandle, LoadLibraryType loadLibraryType);

        public static LoadLibrarySafeHandle New(IntPtr address) => new LoadLibrarySafeHandle(address);
        public static LoadLibrarySafeHandle New(string name, IntPtr fileHandle, LoadLibraryType loadLibraryType) {
            if (GetModuleHandleExW(ModuleHandleType.NONE, name, out IntPtr libraryHandle)) {
                return New(libraryHandle);
            }
            else {
                libraryHandle = LoadLibraryExW(name, fileHandle, loadLibraryType);

                if (IntPtr.Zero == libraryHandle) {
                    throw new DllNotFoundException(message: $"unable to find a library named {name}", inner: Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error()));
                }

                return New(libraryHandle);
            }
        }
        public static LoadLibrarySafeHandle New(string name) => New(name, IntPtr.Zero, LoadLibraryType.NONE);

        private LoadLibrarySafeHandle(IntPtr address) : base(true) {
            SetHandle(address);
        }

        [PrePrepareMethod]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
        protected override bool ReleaseHandle() => FreeLibrary(handle);

        public bool TryGetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegate>(string functionName, out TDelegate functionDelegate) {
            var functionHandle = GetProcAddress(handle, functionName);

            if (IntPtr.Zero == functionHandle) {
                functionDelegate = default;

                return false;
            }
            else {
                functionDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegate>(functionHandle);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
class Program
{
    private delegate IntPtr vkGetInstanceProcAddr(IntPtr instance, IntPtr pName);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var vkDllHandle = Library.LoadLibrarySafeHandle.New("vulkan-1.dll");

        if (vkDllHandle.TryGetDelegateForFunctionPointer(nameof(vkGetInstanceProcAddr), out vkGetInstanceProcAddr vkGetInstanceProcAddrDelegate)) {
            // do something with vkGetInstanceProcAddrDelegate
        }
    }
}
```

**References:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562295/if-i-allocate-some-memory-with-allochglobal-do-i-have-to-free-it-with-freehglob

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About

Answer (score 3):

#### Guidelines when dealing with P/Invoke

- move native methods to nested classes ([Recommendation CA1060](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms182161(v=vs.110)))
- define the libraries to import as constants `const string Kernel32Lib = "Kernel32.dll";` ->  `[DllImport(Kernel32Lib)]`

#### General guidelines

Avoid unnecessary code blocks.

> ```
> if (IntPtr.Zero == functionHandle) {
>     functionDelegate = default;
>
>     return false;
> }
> else {
>     functionDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegate>(functionHandle);
> }
> return true;
> ```

rewritten:

```
if (IntPtr.Zero == functionHandle) {
    functionDelegate = default;
    return false;
}
functionDelegate = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegate>(functionHandle);
return true;
```